# How to open .tsv file automatically by emacsclient when it's downloaded from Chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, emacs

On Mac OS X, with Google Chrome, how to open .tsv file automatically by emacsclient, i.e. opening it in the existing Emacs session if there is one, when the .tsv file is downloaded by Google Chrome?  Right now, it opens it in MacVim automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`emacsclient` has an option `-a` that tells it what editor to run if Emacs is not running. You can use Emacs as the alternative editor.

Comment: Right now, it opens using MacVim.  How to configure it so it opens using Emacs?

Comment: See Automatically open certain types of files at http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95759&topic=14681&ctx=topic